# Jquery does not work in render() method of class but works in componentDidMount()

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux, next.js

I update my packages to latest version. in before there was no error in my project. but after update next js to version 9 and jquery to version 3.5, $.map does not work properly.
when i use $.map in render() method of class component,

```
import $ from "jquery";
.
.
.

render() {

        let rec = [
            {'id':2},
            {'id':3},
            ];

        $.map(rec, function (value) {
            console.log('value',value.id);
        });

        return (
```

it returns this error.

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default.a.map is not a function

> 33 | $.map(rec, function (value) {
     | ^  34 |     console.log('value',value.id);
  35 | });
```

but in componentDidMount it works properly

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        let rec = [
            {'id':2},
            {'id':3},
        ];
        $.map(rec, function (value) {
            console.log('value',value.id);
        });
    }
```

this is my package.json file content:

```
{
  "name": "ssr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "author": "Emmanuel Henri",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.8",
    "@zeit/next-css": "1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "next": "^9.3.6",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-datepicker2": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "package": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple problems here:

- In general, you shouldn't be using jQuery in a React app.  jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation library.  React creates and updates DOM, and if other code modifies the DOM that React "owns", things tend to break.  (There are times when you might need to have some interop between React and jQuery, like wrapping a jQuery plugin in a React component as an app is being migrated, but most of the time use of React means you shouldn't use jQuery at all.)
- Don't use `$.map()` for looping over arrays.  Arrays already have a built in `Array.map()` function.
- Since `render()` will run for the first time before the component mounts, it's very likely that the global `$` variable hasn't been initialized yet somehow.

But yeah, *don't* use jQuery here.

Comment: I have been working with jquery for 2 years and It's very difficult for me to code with raw Javascript.
before updating the next js (v5-> v9) , I was work with jquery in React and there was no problem

Comment: As I said, when using React, you almost never need jQuery, and you really _shouldn't_ be using jQuery with React except in very rare cases.